# Different values trigger the SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas dataframe inside a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have very weird case of a warning appearing quite randomly.
EDIT: Please note that this question is not about how to deal with the warning but why it appears/disappears based on what is a single value in a data frame.

I have two files - test1.csv with:

```
A,B,C
0,-0.7071068,0
```

and - test2.csv with:

```
A,B,C
0,0,0
```

I get the warning

```
c:\libs\python36-32\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: 
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

when using the first file with the code (first file):

```
df = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
df['B'][df['B'] > -1] = np.nan
```

but not with (same code, second file):

```
df = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
df['B'][df['B'] > -1] = np.nan
```

In each case running the code results in suggesting the warning is wrong (the change goes through, so I'm not working with a copy):

```
   A    B   C
0  0  NaN   0
```

I'm on Windows 10 with Python 3.6.5 64-bit, Jupyter 4.4.0 and Pandas 0.23.3

Comment: So `df.loc[df['B'] > -1, 'B'] = np.nan` not working?

Comment: It can be used to hide the warning, but it does not explain why: 
B = -0.7071068 => warning appears,
B = 0 => warning does not appear.
In other words, why does changing the column type from float to int affect the behavior?